# Can a TP-LINK TL-WN951N be made to work on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008

I just bought this wireless network card which advertises support for Windows 7 and runs fine on it when the driver is installed.  However on Windows Server 2008 R2, the driver installs but doesn't actually discover any WiFi networks. Diagnostics reports:

> There might be a problem with the driver for the Wi-Fi adapter.

Does anyone know whether I could expect this brand to work, or have a brand they recommend?

Comment: Can I ask why you're putting a very cheap consumer-grade WiFi card in a server? Or any WiFi card in a server? No shopping recommendations on StackExchange btw.

Comment: My apologies for the inappropriate use of this forum then.  This server is at my home, and wifi is the only way to get Internet connectivity in that room.  I'm running a server OS so I can use Hyper-V.

Comment: Just trying to clarify where this belongs - I'll flag this for migration to SuperUser. My suggestions would be a wireless access point or wireless router in bridge mode rather than a wireless NIC.